# Books on Inequalities and Geometry

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for suggestions of books on inequalities and geometry.

I'm specifically asking this because I'm not looking for a book that is suited for students preparing for mathematics competition. I won't mind the books having a good bunch of approachable and challenging questions, but I'm looking for a book for personal edification, and reviewing and building on the basics which are usually taught in a not-so-rigorous and complete manner in high school.

Answer (score 3):

This one is oriented towards competition level Geometry:

$\qquad$Kedlaya -- Geometry Unbound (2006)

Moreover, the author made it freely available:

$\qquad$http://kskedlaya.org/geometryunbound/gu-060118.pdf

Here's one from AoPS, also free:

[Members of Mathlinks] -- Geometric Inequalities Marathon 1 - The First 100 Problems and Solutions (2011)

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiQ45GGlZHUAhUB4yYKHSBNDbEQFggxMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkskedlaya.org%2Fgeometryunbound%2Fgu-060118.pdf&usg=AFQjCNExuDbA2Tjx1IcoVd4gCKdWtbT9ww&sig2=X_H11SC0dz5HvBHHiynQQQ&cad=rja

It downloads to a file called "Geometry", with no extension, so you may need to rename it so that the extension is ".pdf"

Answer (score 1):

A great and insightful book on inequalities of various type is the book:

[Inequalities](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Inequalities.html?id=t1RCSP8YKt8C&hl=fr)

of G. H. Hardy, J. E. Littlewood and G. Pólya.

I especially like it as it explains also the underlying mechanism behind  inequalities. It gives also a great overview of all types of means inequalities as well as their generalizations (in many different directions).

Comment: Yes, I was looking at this book just yesterday. The book seems great, but I was looking for another book before covering Hardy's book. Also, I think it's one of the books that should be covered if one has some time on one's hand. Like Hardy's other textbooks, the book seems to be a huge exercise. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly not yet mentioned is Volume #4 in the well known *New Mathematical Library* series:

[**Geometric Inequalities**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883856042) by Nicholas D. Kazarinoff (originally appeared in 1961) [see here also](http://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/geometric-inequalities)

Also in this series (Volume #3) is

[**An Introduction to Inequalities**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883856034) by Edwin F. Beckenbach and Richard E. Bellman (originally appeared in 1961) [see here also](http://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/an-introduction-to-inequalities)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Advanced Olympiad Inequalities: Algebraic & Geometric Olympiad Inequalities](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1794193928), it deals with both algebraic and geometric inequalities. The book contains around 300 solved problems with more than one solutions for many problems. It has also a variety of unsolved problems that were left as extra challenges to the reader.